# Why KeyPoint "detector" and "extractor" are different operation?

Tags: opencv, sift, surf

Bascially you have first to do a:

```
SurfFeatureDetector surf(400);
surf.detect(image1, keypoints1);
```

And then a:

```
surfDesc.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
```

Why detect and comput are 2 different operation?
Doing the computing after the detect doesn't make redundance loops?

I found myself that `.compute` is the most expensive in my application.

```
.detect
```

is done in **0.2secs**

```
.compute
```

Takes **~1sec**. Is there any way to speed up `.compute` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between detecting the keypoints in an image and computing the descriptors for those keypoints. For example you can extract SURF keypoints and compute SIFT features. Note that in DescriptorExtractor::compute method, filters on keypoints are applied:

```
KeyPointsFilter::runByImageBorder()
KeyPointsFilter::runByKeypointSize();
```

Comment: HMM that's interesting! do you know any way to compute it in a faster way? My profile shows that `.compute` is the part that takes more time than other

Comment: It depends on your application's need but you should try BRIEF descriptor. They are designed to be faster to compute than SURF and are very similar. If you really want to use SURF, you may want to select less points in your image or filter them in a smart way (with spatial constraing ?).

Comment: yes I was thinking that (select less keypoint) Would you filter the vector of keypoint after having calcluate it (with `.detect`) or a prior select few keypoints? (maybe with hessian threshold?)

Comment: second option but it really depends on your app's need.

Comment: Yea second options looks cleary faster. But how do you tell to `featureDetector.detect()` to select less keypoints ?

Comment: You need to re-implement/overload the method and customize it.

Comment: Then first option is the way to go XD

Answer (score 9):

The detection of keypoints is just a process for selecting points in the image that are considered "good features".

The extraction of descriptors of those keypoints is a completely different process that encodes properties of that feature like contrast with neighbours etc so it can be compared with other keypoints from different images, different sclae and orientation.

The way you describe a keypoint could be crucial for a successful matching, and this is really the key factor. Also the way you describe a keypoint is determinant for the matching speed. For example you can describe it as a float or as a binary secuence.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from where Jay_Rock left, you can improve those processing times by using a binary descriptor offered by algorithms like ORB, Brisk or FREAK. Not only will they occupy 32 bit instead of 64, they also offer different methods for computing descriptors that are as robust as SURF's and much faster.

If you eventually want to perform matching operations between descriptors, this is done by calculating the Hamming distance between both. Given that it's a XOR operation between two binary strings, it takes only a few milliseconds to run.